# "The lake is only the ninth largest lake in the area at 395 miles (620 kilometres) in length and 46 miles (74 kilometres) in width"

Tags: sentence-construction

> The lake is only the ninth largest lake in the area at 395 miles (620 kilometres) in length and 46 miles (74 kilometres) in width, yet it is easily the largest body of fresh water in the world.

What’s wrong with “only the …, yet it is…”? Should “only the” be replaced by “not only” or am I missing something?

Comment: Hello and welcome to the ELL. On this site it is better to ask one question at a time. Have a look at the [tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn how to do that.

Comment: Thanks for editing. I have an answer, so tag me in a comment when this question opens again

Comment: The problem with it isn't its use of "only." It has two problems: one, "in the area" is too subjective and vague to be used with giving something a ranking of ninth-largest; two, a lake can't possibly be only the ninth-largest in the area yet be the largest body of fresh water in the world, not unless you're using two different definitions of "largest," which would need to be stated, like by saying "the ninth-largest in area" (different than "in *the* area," "in *the* area" meaning in the vicinity and "in area" meaning in square miles of surface) and then saying "yet the largest in volume."

Comment: Hard to imagine that the world's biggest fresh lake is a neighbor to eight *even bigger* salt lakes!

Comment: @gotube,
It appears that the question is open to comments again, thanks

Comment: @BenjaminHarman,
Thank you for your response. The line is actually taken from a TOEFL iBT preparation book and the grammar behind "only the ..., yet" seemed strange, as if something like "not" before "only" is missing or maybe I'm missing something. Anyway, I just provide you with the actual sentence.
Crescent-shaped Lake Baikal, in Siberia, is only the ninth largest lake in area at 395 miles (620 kilometers) in length and 46 miles (74 kilometers) in width, yet it is easily the largest body of fresh water in the world.

Comment: Jeffrey Carney's answer below is spot on

Answer (score 1):

You have in fact missed something. We use the "not only . . . but" structure when we want to show how a **similarity** between things intensifies the meaning. For example:

> Stephan is not only the ninth most handsome man in the world, but he is also the third most intelligent.

The point of the sentence is that Stephan is a special person in many ways.

In the Lake Baikal example, the author means to **contrast** the two qualities. It is surprising that the largest lake by volume should be the ninth largest by area. Intuition suggests that the largest lake by volume should also be the largest lake by area.

This is the context in which "only" makes sense.

> Yes, it is true that Lake Baikal is the largest in volume. But it is *only* the ninth largest in area. Isn't that surprising?

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply
What I got from your answer is that "not only ... but" structure is used to draw similarity, while "only ... yet" applies for contrasting, Is that so?
Speaking of that paradox you've mentioned, I suppose taking "freshwater" into account justifies the way it is. Like contrasting between salt water and fresh water.

Comment: I think you understand!